# Custom unicode sorting order for PouchDB/CouchDB Index (Mango Query)

Tags: sorting, unicode, couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-mango

I am using [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) (with a [Cloudant](http://cloudant.com/) remote database) to have a local database in a dictionary web app.

I need to have an index with a custom Pashto alphabet order (using [Arabic unicode letters](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/arabic/)).

The `localdb.find` queries with `$gte` (alphabetically searching with partial words) do not work well because of the irregular Unicode characters in the Pashto alphabet.

Is it possible to create a custom sort, based on the [Pashto alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashto_alphabet), for an index?

See [Mango Query Language](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

In [this reference](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html) it is mentioned that:

> The most important feature of a view result is that it is sorted by key.

Assume you have a database consisting of docs with a `unicodeString` field inside each doc. So a sample doc would look like below:

```
{
    "_id":"2018-01-30-18-04-11",
    "_rev":"AE19EBC7654",

    "title":"Hello elephant",
    "unicodeString":"שלום פיל",
}
```

Now you can have a CouchDB view with a map function like this:

```
function(doc) {
    emit(doc.unicodeString, doc.title); // doc.unicodeString is key
                                        // doc.title         is value
}
```

The above view sorts all the docs inside the database according to its `key` which is `doc.unicodeString`. Therefore, if you use the above view, all of your docs would be sorted based on your Unicode string inside docs.

---

If you have 3 docs in database, when you query the above view, you receive a response result like this in which `rows` array is sorted according to `key` in each `row`:

```
{
    "total_rows": 3,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "key": "ארץ",
            "id": "2017-09-01-09-05-11",
            "value": "Earth"
        },

        {
            "key": "בין",
            "id": "2015-01-19-11-30-28",
            "value": "between"
        },

        {
            "key": "שלום פיל",
            "id": "2018-01-30-18-04-11",
            "value": "Hello elephant"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my question was about how to create a custom sort order for the unicode string / key. I still need to create a custom sort order based on a rarer alphabet.